# How the code execute immediately without hit the button?

Tags: javascript

I made a very simple Ajax test code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='main.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='get-content'>Click</button>
        <p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
(function(){
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        var xml_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml_request.open('GET', '/test.txt', true);
        xml_request.addEventListener('readystatechange', change_content);
        var button_element = document.getElementById('get-content'); 
        button_element.addEventListener('click', fireup(xml_request));
        function fireup(xml_request) {
            xml_request.send();
        }
        function change_content(){
            if (xml_request.readyState == 4 && xml_request.status == 200) {
                document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].textContent = xml_request.responseText;
            };  
        };
    });
})();
```

it works, but except, the ajax request send and change the p tag, without I hit the button,
any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
button_element.addEventListener('click', fireup(xml_request));
```

In this line, you *call* `fireup(xml_request)`, and assign whatever it returns (nothing) as a listener for the `click` event. You probably want something like this:

```
button_element.addEventListener('click', fireup);
function fireup() { ...
```

Since `xml_request` is in scope for the `fireup` function, you don't need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: thanks man, it works, but I want to know why passing the `xml_request` to the fireup will cause the content change immediately

Comment: @yozloy because you are _calling_ the function. There is a big difference between `fireup` and `fireup()`

Comment: @JanDvorak WOW, thanks for totally clear up my confusion, if I need to pass parameter to it I should use `function(){ fire up(param1)}`, am I right?

Comment: @yozloy except for the space in the function name, this is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you call it when you add listener : `fireup(xml_request)`.
it should be like : `button_element.addEventListener('click', fireup); function fireup () {...`

you could also use an anonymous function `button_element.addEventListener('click', function () {...})`

Comment: This will cause `fireup` to invoke `undefined.send()`